# Issues Running SSIS Package with DTExec.exe in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: cmd.exe, ssis, visual-studio-2022

I am currently facing a issue while attempting to run an SSIS package using the DTExec.exe tool found in the Visual Studio 2022 folder. I can successfully execute the SSIS package within Visual Studio itself.

However, when I attempt to run the same package using the Command Prompt (CMD) and DTExec.exe, it fails to execute.

When I run it in 64-bit DTEXEC then it results in a DTS error like below:

[Could not create DTS.Application because of error 0x80040154](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJcTz.png)

The command I use in CMD (running the 64-bit DTEXEC) is below:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\160\Binn\DTExec.exe" /f "C:\Users\Me\Documents\Repo\project\pipelines\test_3.dtsx"
```

Note: The 32-bit version of DTEXEC is not being used as it causes a version error:

```
Error: 2023-11-02 15:12:08.18
   Code: 0xC001700A
   Source: Package1
   Description: The version number in the package is not valid. The version number cannot be greater than current version number.
End Error
Error: 2023-11-02 15:12:08.18
   Code: 0xC0016020
   Source: Package1
   Description: Package migration from version 8 to version 6 failed with error 0xC001700A "The version number in the package is not valid. The version number cannot be greater than current version number.".
End Error
```

I have tried to use different versions of DTEXEC, with no success so far.

Have also tested with different Command Prompt variations such as the DTEXEC /Project (Project) /Package (Package Name) but then I still get the following error:

```
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 16.0.5131.0 for 64-bit
Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft. All rights reserved.
 
Started:  02:26:23 PM
Could not create DTS.Application because of error 0x80040154
Started:  02:26:23 PM
Finished: 02:26:23 PM
Elapsed:  0 seconds
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: It appears that you may be either A) trying to run a package created for a higher version of SSIS than you have installed, or B) you don't have the SSIS feature installed. You can almost always find an answer by Googling the error code:. Here's the very first result I got: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/786465/remote-execution-of-dtexec-exe-produces-error-0x80